# Unable to Add certificate to X509Store

Tags: c#, x509certificate

Im trying to add a certificate to a certificate store programatically 
I'm using the following code to fetch a pfx file from a directory and add the certificate to the CurrentUser under My store.
The code runs without any exception but I'm not able to see the certificate added in the store.
I've tried changing CurrentUser to LocalMachine and have also tried adding under TrustedPeople but with no success.

```
X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("<filepath>"), "<pswd>", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet );
                StorePermission sp =
            new StorePermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            sp.Flags = StorePermissionFlags.AllFlags;
            sp.Assert();
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
            store.Certificates.Add(cer);
        store.Close();
```

Comment: How do you know the code succeeds? Have you wrapped it in a `try/catch` and set a breakpoint in the catch block?

Comment: Yes I've put this in a try catch but there is no exception. Also if i debug and check the store.Certificates collection after the Add statement, the new cert is not added in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
store.Add(cer);
```

instead of

```
store.Certificates.Add(cer);
```